# Optimal method for estimating geometric mean ratio using Bayesian log transformed data

Tags: bayesian, data-transformation, logarithm

I'm working on a Bayesian analysis with a categorical variable involving two groups (A vs B). I'm seeking advice on the best method to compute the geometric mean ratio (GMR) together with the highest posterior density interval (HPDI). My model is `log(response) ~ 0 + group`, resulting in posterior distributions for the means of each group on a log scale.

I am considering two approaches, both including the calculation of the HPDI:

1. **Estimate, then backtransform:** Calculate the difference of the distributions on the log scale, determine the mean and HPDI of this distribution, and then backtransform these estimates.
2. **Backtransform, then estimate:** Compute the difference between the two posterior distributions on the log scale, backtransform the entire distribution, then calculate the mean and HPDI of the backtransformed distribution.

Which method is more standard or recommended in Bayesian analysis for accurately computing and interpreting the GMR and HPDI?